# How to implicitly join across collections in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, orm

The object structure is like below-

```
Entity A
  - Collection <B>

Entity B
  - Collection <C>

Entity C
  -Collection <D>

Entity D
  CompositePrimaryKey

Class CompositePrimaryKey
  String id;
```

In the HQL, the query is like **from A a where a.B.C.D.CompositePrimaryKey.id = 'input';**

I am getting the below exception-

org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection

Basically this is implicit join across the collections.
What is the right approach to do this?

I want to fetch all data through the collections - based on the id value

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge HQL cannot dereference this complicated case. You need to specify the mapping for child collections as `fetch="join"` and write a big HQL join manually:

```
from A_table a, B_table b, C_table c, D_table d
  where a.b_id = b.id and b.c_id = c.id and c.d_id = d.id and d.id = 'input'
```

A good solution will also be to define the [filter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html#objectstate-filters) for entity `A` (filters operate with table columns):

```
<class name="A" ...>
    ...
    <filter name="id_filter" condition="D_table.id = :id" />
</class>
```

Comment: I used the filter logic and it works fine for my requirement, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting the (...) exception org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection

The path expression `a.B.C.D` is illegal as B (and C and D) is a collection.

> Basically this is implicit join across the collections. What is the right approach to do this?

Use an explicit join:

```
from A a join a.B b join b.C c join c.D d where d.pk.id = :id
```

Comment: I like this join syntax better than the old where clause join syntax.